# encoding php postgres json_encode

Tags: php, postgresql, encoding, json

I have a problem with my encoding...

Everything is UTF-8 configured, namely my database (postgres) and my php files.

when I execute this script:

```
$eleves = $serviceManager->getAll('Eleve');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($eleves);
echo "</pre>";
```

I get this:

```
 [0] => Model_Eleve Object
    (
        [idEleve:Model_Eleve:private] => 28206
        [numeroscolaire:Model_Eleve:private] => ABE290999JOËL
        [nom:Model_Eleve:private] => Abedinpour
        [prenom:Model_Eleve:private] => Joël
        [dateNaissance:Model_Eleve:private] => 1999-09-29
        [sexe:Model_Eleve:private] => masculin
        [statusCourant:Model_Eleve:private] =>
        [statusSuivant:Model_Eleve:private] =>
        [adresses:Model_Eleve:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => Model_Adresse Object
                    (
                        [idAdresse:Model_Adresse:private] => 6176
                        [rue:Model_Adresse:private] => La Delèze
                        [numero:Model_Adresse:private] => 37
                        [codePostal:Model_Adresse:private] => 1164
                        [localite:Model_Adresse:private] => Buchillon
                        [emplacement:Model_Adresse:private] =>
                    )

            )
```

Here everything's ok. But if I want JSON:

```
$eleves = $serviceManager->getAll('Eleve');
echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($eleves, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "</pre>";
```

I get this:

```
{
    "nom": "Abedinpour",
    "prenom": "Jo\u00ebl",
    "adresse": [
        {
            "rue": "La Del\u00e8ze",
            "numero": "37",
            "localite": "Buchillon"
        }
    ],
    "classe": [
        "7VSG\/1"
    ]
},
```

I have no idea why it works with array and doesn't work with json_encode... I've tried to transform everything in utf8 (with htmlentities) but it tells me that he can't convert 'ASCII'

When I try to show the encoding of my files with this command in the terminal:

```
file -I myfile.php
```

it returns this:

```
myfile.php: text/x-php; charset=us-ascii
```

but i can't convert it to utf8:

```
iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 myfile.php > myfile2.php
file -I myfile2.php
myfile2.php: text/x-php; charset=us-ascii
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the perfectly valid JSON way to encode non-ASCII characters. Nothing is wrong here. Any client properly decoding this will retrieve the correct character. If you prefer actual UTF-8 characters and are running PHP 5.4+, use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag for `json_encode`.

Comment: yeah it works great! but is it possible to have both JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE and JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ? I've tried this:
    $eleves2 = json_encode($eleves, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    $eleves3 = json_encode($eleves2, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
but it doesn't work...

Comment: The parameter is a bit flag, to pass two *OR* them: `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`.

Comment: Oups I just found: json_encode($eleves, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); Thanks for your help!